# How to implement a FIFO using a stack(LIFO) with equal complexities for push and pop operations of FIFO

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack, fifo

I understood the traditional way of making either Push operation expensive or pop operation expensive.

How to make push and pop to have equal complexity?

Comment: have 2 stack pointers one for pushing in and one for popping out

Comment: I can use only push() , pop() ,isempty() functions of a stack. No pointers are allowed ( Pointers would make the problem very simple).

Comment: @PaulHankin : I am trying to equalize the complexities of Insert() and take() functions of your link's top answer.

Comment: If you follow the links in the discussion of that question, you can find eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538192/how-to-implement-a-queue-with-three-stacks .

Answer (score 2):

This is standard interview question.
Common idea: minus x minus = plus.
You use 2 sequenced stacks:

- PUT deploys data to a stack 1.
- GET extracts data from stack 2.
- If stack2 is empty - copy all existing data from stack 1 to stack 2, element by element, from top 1 to top 2.

Comment: +1. But please note that this results in *amortized* constant time: every so often, the 'pop' operation will be expensive (because it has to copy everything over at once), but this averages out to constant time, since the cost of that one expensive 'pop' is proportional to the number of subsequent inexpensive 'pops'.